# Login to Orchard CMS using email address

Tags: authentication, orchardcms

The title is already succinct enough.
Is it possible to have users login with their email address instead of username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the default behavior - either the username or email address can be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It wasn't written anywhere.